# How to handle empty and full objects in a Knockout ViewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I can't seem to find the answers I am looking for on stack. Maybe my scenario is just wrong but I'm going to ask the question anyway. I have a form which serves two purposes... Create new user and View User. Both have the same view model `User`. So let's look at my viewmodel:

```
var UserModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.UserId = ko.observable();
    self.FirstName = ko.observable();
    self.LastName = ko.observable();

    self.FirstName.extend({required: true});

    return self;
}
```

So my bindings are configured at a higher level, I have a viewmodel with a property called `User`. this property called `User` is bound to my form. For the simple scenario of creating a new user I would call:

```
this.User(new UserModel());
```

Note: `this.User` is observable, hence the brackets.

this will successfully create my user model with a blank form and all validation works.

Ok so scenario two! I get an full object from the API, how should I map this. If I use:

```
this.User(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, UserModel));
```

the validation doesn't work. I have seen the mapping options which include the `create` method, but how do I use this without losing the functionality at the top?!

---

As a side note to make it a little more complicated:

`User.ConfirmEmail` exists in my viewmodel but not on the server! So that is my next hurdle. If I use the `create` mapping I know I can easily add it.

---

### My Current Working Example

By using lots of constructor parameters I can accomplish both:

```
var UserModel = function(id, fname, lname) {
    var self = this;

    self.UserId = ko.observable(id);
    self.FirstName = ko.observable(fname);
    self.LastName = ko.observable(lname);

    self.FirstName.extend({required: true});

    return self;
}
```

If I now use, `new UserModel()` it still sets the properties up and I can also pass through the values. It just looks bad :(

Answer (score 2):

Separate the creation of the user from the adding of the validation rule:

```
function userFactory(user) {

    if (typeof user === 'undefined') {
        user = new User();
    }

    user.firstName.extend({required: true});

}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var newUser = userFactory(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, new UserModel()));
this.user(newUser);
```

... and keep the Validation.